# Съезжает фон при уменьшении масштаба страницы(адаптив)

Tags: html, css

[image: норм]
[image: Грязь]
[image: грязь2]

Съезжает картинка с фоном при масштабировании, все перепробовал хз че делать, единтсвенной с чем не съезжает это если background-attachment: fixed, но мне не нужен этот эффект. хелп вот код фона

```
position: relative;
background: url(../img/prices.jpg) no-repeat center center;
width: 100%;
min-height: 808px;
padding: 100px 0px 74px;
```

Comment: Если правильно понял, то просто добавьте background-size: cover; тогда картинка будет заполнять весь блок при любых размерах.

Comment: да, добавлял, но всеравно верстка съезжала, решил проблему увеличением размера фона при разной ширине экрана